# Convert URI into JSON using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, uri

Im having some troubles finding information on a good way to take URI data and convert it into JSON using JQuery.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and output? Maybe [this question about extracting query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) helps. I assume you know how to convert a JavaScript object to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)?

and the answer from the question felix pointed out is good too

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```